# Cannot check iframe window location from a website with different origin

Tags: javascript, iframe, window, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have a script that create an iframe like this, and I use the iframe to check authentication then redirect the main `window` :

```
var target "https://my.website.it"
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

iframe.id = "my-frame";
iframe.src = "/my-url/that?redirect=true&target=" + target
iframe.onload = function() {
  iframeFn();
};
```

into the `iframeFn()` function I want to check the location of the iframe itself to perform some controls before redirect:

```
function iframeFn() {
  var myFrame = document.getElementById("my-frame");
  var iframeWindow = myFrame.contentWindow;
  if (iframeWindow.location.search.search(/fail/) >= 0) {
    window.location = '/'
  }
```

I put this script in a cdn and I use this script in a website with the same origin url of the redirect target (`https://my.website.it`), and it works. But if I try to use this script in a website with different origin (`https://different.website.it`) I got this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://different.website.it" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at reloadInIFrame (https://static.website.it/my-script.js:34:29)
at HTMLIFrameElement.iframe.onload (https://static.website.it/.js:82:5)
```

at this line

```
if (iframeWindow.location.search.search(/fail/) >= 0) {
```

I've read this: [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) but I can't figure out how to use `window.postMessage` in my case.

**NB**: the second level domain is the same in both cases (`website.it`)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you control both domains?

Comment: @epascarello I'm working with the other team developers to find a common solution

Comment: Cross Domain does not allow you to access the iframe. If you control both domains you use postmessage between the windows. Other than that you are stuck because of the same origin policy that is protecting us from bad intent.